# MATLAB: One looped plot closing other figures

Tags: matlab

I have three functions in MATLAB. First two create their own figures. Third one plots in loop.

```
%First function: 
figure(1);
ax(1) = subplot(3,1,1);
plot(Time,X, '-m');
hold on
plot(Time,X2,'-k');
..

%Second function:
figure(2);
..

%Third function:
for i = 1: length(data)
    figure(3);
    subplot(2,2,[1 2]);
    ..
end
```

As soon as third function is called, the other two figures are closed. I want then to remain open. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a `close` command, you can't really tell from your minimal code a lot. Also, take the third figure command out of the loop, you'll keep rewriting it:

```
figure(3);
for i = 1: length(data)
    subplot(2,2,[1 2]);
    ..
end
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I really am a n00b. It was close all being called in the third function, I once put and had forgotten about it.